# Is there a way to remove inlined functions from the call stack in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: c++, xcode, lldb

I know that the recent versions of Xcode shows inlined functions and allows stepping inside inlined code. I'm trying to debug code that make heavy use of std::function and I would really prefer if both the call stack and the step-in operation would simply skip all the implementation details of std::function. The new libc++ marks those details with attribute "always_inline" so that they are always inlined (even in debug builds) which is exactly what I want. In fact, since I'm not debugging the std::function implementation, I just don't want to see these functions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that right now.  You can change the way lldb reports stack frames in a backtrace -- see http://lldb.llvm.org/formats.html -- but I can't think of any way to get it to suppress the (synthesized) inline stack frames from your backtrace.  gdb had a setting to avoid parsing all inlined information in the debug info - no stepping, no backtracing - but that hasn't been added to lldb.

Realistically, you really don't want to turn off inlined code support stepping. Without identifying which code is inlined, the "next" or "step over" mode of stepping breaks horribly with inlined code.  Xcode 4.6 is pretty good at this - but the remaining cases were you "step over" a source line with inlined code and you see the actual inlined implementation from a `.h` file is because of incorrect debug information from the compiler.  Getting this debug info correct is tricky and while the majority of it is correct, you'll still end up in an inlined method on occasion with Xcode 4.6.  Possibly for the containers you're using, you're hitting it a lot - but that's not the common case.

lldb does give you a way to customize the output of `bt`, see http://lldb.llvm.org/formats.html , but there's no way to have it suppress inlined stack frames.  You can write a stack walker in python pretty easily that does the same thing as a real `bt` but skips inlined frames - the `SBFrame::IsInlined()` method makes this simple.  But that wouldn't help in the instance where you're using Xcode.

Comment: The ocasional "step over" bugs don't bother me. I'm more concerned with trying to debug my recursive code... I guess what I'm asking for is a mode that take into account all debug information but that simply filters out the inlined frames and always automatically step over inlined code (stopping when reaching a real function call).

Comment: Ah, OK, I think I see what you're getting at.  You're doing `step` over something like `vector.push_back` and you don't want to actually step into an inlined implementation of that.  You may try using the `target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp` setting, like `settings set target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp ^[^ ]+ std::|^std::` in your `~/.lldbinit` file.